# why the while body is executed?

Tags: c++

I have the following program:

```
int main() {
  int i;
  while (cin >> i) {
    cout << abs(i) << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

(where abs is defined by int abs(int val))

when I input a non-int number, for example, -1.2, it will give the following output:

```
$ -1.2
1
```

My question is: why the while body gets executed? I think the condition should fail as soon as I input a non-int value and the program should terminate. Thanks!

Comment: what is cin,count,endl, and in what language is this?

Comment: @Wasafa1 The tag at the bottom of the question (above the links) says C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the input operator reads `-1`, and stops at the dot. Next time through the loop the input operator sees the dot and sets the `fail` flag, terminating the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your program only reads one integer, not any more than that. If you use `cin` to read an int value the operator will only read an int, so using a decimal will make it only read up to the dot. Entering -55.365, for example, would really only send -55.